# How to create a .tar.gz file from text string

Tags: c#, gzip, tar

I have a dlm file and I want to create a .tar.gz file from the content in dlm file. When I am trying to create the file, it is created but when I manually unzip that it is failed. My code is below for creating .tar.gz file,  targetFileName is like C:\Folder\xxx.tar.gz:

```
 using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(targetFileName, false, Encoding.Default))
 {
        write.Write(text.ToString());
        write.Close();
 }
```

In the above code text is content from dlm file. Is there anything that I am missing? please help.

Comment: _"Is there anything I am missing"_ - yes, you are. You're just writing a text file. You're not adding the data to a tarball or gzipping it. In case it's not clear: simply writing the extension `.tar.gz` doesn't create a gzipped tarball any more than renaming a `.bmp` to a `.exe` makes it a program.

Answer (score 2):

try use [SharpZipLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/) from Nuget

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar;
```

add method:

```
private static void CreateTarGZ(string tgzFilename, string innerFilename, string text)
    {
        var uncompressed = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        using (Stream outStream = File.Create(tgzFilename))
        {
            using (GZipOutputStream gzoStream = new GZipOutputStream(outStream))
            {
                gzoStream.SetLevel(9);
                using (TarOutputStream taroStream = new TarOutputStream(gzoStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    taroStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
                    TarEntry entry = TarEntry.CreateTarEntry(innerFilename);
                    entry.Size = uncompressed.Length;
                    taroStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    taroStream.Write(uncompressed, 0, uncompressed.Length);
                    taroStream.CloseEntry();
                    taroStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then call:

```
CreateTarGZ("test.tar.gz", "FileName.txt", "my text");
CreateTarGZ("c:\\temp\\test.tar.gz", "foo-folder\\FileName.txt", "my text");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick example to create a `.tar.gz` and `.gz` file that will include the file that you might be creating using the `stream`.

Note that I'm using `SharpZipLib` which you can find in Nuget Package Manager for you project. Then make sure to add reference in your code:

### Making tar.gz

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        string text = ".Net is Awesome";
        string filename = "D:\\text.txt";
        string tarfilename = "D:\\text.tar.gz";
        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.Default))
        {
            //Writing a text file
            write.Write(text.ToString());
            write.Close();

            //Creating a tar.gz Stream
            Stream TarFileStream = File.Create(tarfilename);
            Stream GZStream = new GZipOutputStream(TarFileStream);
            TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(GZStream);
            tarArchive.RootPath = "D:/"; //Setting the Root Path for the archive

            //Creating a file entry for the tar archive
            TarEntry tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(filename);

            //Writing the entry in the archive.
            tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, false); //set false to only add the concerned file in the archive.
            tarArchive.Close();
        }
}
```

### Making only .gz

You can create a method to make it more reusable like:

```
private static void MakeGz(string targetFile)
{
      string TargetGz = targetFile + ".gz";
      using (Stream GzStream = new GZipOutputStream(File.Create(TargetGz)))
      {
           using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(targetFile))
           {
               byte[] FileBuffer = new byte[fs.Length];
               fs.Read(FileBuffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
               GzStream.Write(FileBuffer, 0, FileBuffer.Length);
               fs.Close();
               GzStream.Close();
            }
      }
 }
```

Then you can call this method whenever you are creating a file to make an archive for the same at the same time like:

```
 MakeGz(filename);
```